# AMD CPU overclocking software?

Tags: ati, overclocking

Is there a program for Ubuntu that I can use to overclock my AMD Phenom(tm) II X2 560 Processor?

Comment: http://www.xbitlabs.com/articles/cpu/display/amd-phenom-ii-x6-1055t-overclocking_3.html#sect0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only program that I know about, is called TurionPowerControl.  It hasn`t been fully tested yet, but if interested you can [download and find more information here](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?26065-New-tool-for-undervolt-overclock-AMD-K8L-and-K10-processors).

Comment: Quoted fro the site: TurionPowerControl is a nice command line tool for Windows and Linux that allows users to tweak AMD processors parameters. It is available in both 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

It currently supports AMD Family 10h processors - All Phenom, **Phenom II**, Athlon II and Turion II processors

Comment: Sorry, I completely misread the title *even as I was reading it over again to quote it!* You're quite right--this utility certainly does support overclocking. My bad!