# Can I overclock my cpu using cpupowerd?

Tags: overclocking

I've been trying to look for ways to overclock my rather old cpu, AMD Turion 64 x2 Tl-56 1.8ghz dual core. My Acer Aspire 5100 series bios does not give me the option to overclock. After referring to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/146139/114660) and [this thread I found using google](http://www.overclock.net/t/1205257/overclock-cpu-in-linux-necessary-program-names-given), I came to the conclusion the only utility that supports AMD's k8 processor family was cpupowerd. I downloaded the code [here](http://cpupowerd.sourceforge.net/), compiled it with

```
make && sudo make install
```

loaded the msr kernel module with

```
sudo modprobe msr
```

and ran it with

```
sudo ./cpupowerd --freq "0|1900"
```

which returned the following message:

```
cpupowerd 0.2.1 written by Markus Strobl.
WARNING: This program could cause damage to your Hardware!
Frequency 1900 MHz not available!
```

I then did

```
sudo ./cpupowerd -s
```

which returned

```
cpupowerd 0.2.1 written by Markus Strobl.
WARNING: This program could cause damage to your Hardware!
Vendor                      : AMD
Family                      : K8
Model                       : 4
  Mastercpuid               : 0
    Affected cpuids         : 0 1
    Current voltage (VID)   : 1.1000 V (18)
    Current frequency (FID) : 1800 MHz (10)
    Supported frequencies   : 800 1600 1800 MHz
```

It doesn't want to set the frequency to something other that what's on the supported frequencies list. Is there any way for more to override it or alter it? Alternatively, is there another utility I could use to overclock my cpu on Ubuntu?

I am able to use cpupowerd as is to set the frequency to 800mhz and 1.6ghz.

Comment: Overclocking the AMD turion i dont think this is supported with ubuntu.

Comment: I think you have to use a certain multiples when setting clock speed. Like how bits come in multiples of 8 (8,32,64 etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Supported frequencies   : 800 1600 1800 MHz

This is telling you what frequencies the CPU core allows. If you don't use these, cpupowerd will refuse to change the frequencies. Try using instead:

```
sudo ./cpupowerd --freq "0|1800"
sudo ./cpupowerd --freq "0|1600"
sudo ./cpupowerd --freq "0|800"
```

Also, remember that **not all cores allow overclocking**, which is what I suspect it's happening.