# Overclocking AMD processor

Tags: 13.10, ati, overclocking

I was wondering if there are any overclocking tools that would work with an AMD A10 5745M processor. Really all I need to do is be able to manage my cpu clock speed and IF possible cpu temp and stability test. But I'll settle for just managing my clock speed. I am running Ubuntu 13.10. Please help

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/146139/amd-cpu-overclocking-software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise if it's possible to overclock via BIOS I don't trust overclocking software only if testing overclock software you can run a memtest in recovery mode also and so on...

useful software is [CPU-G](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cpug/) alike CPU-Z

You can also install [Psensor](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/monitor-hardware-temperature-in-ubuntu.html) for temperature control

if you want to heavy load your processor to test its workabillity you can use [mprime](http://ubuntuxtreme.com/howto/how-to-test-your-systems-stability/)

and you can install `sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq` to change frequencies if it works for you. Hope this is plenty enough for you.

Comment: The link of CPU-G opens up a porn site

Comment: haha indeed, probably it was hacked or smth, I replaced it